# How to get rid of operation confirmation window?

Tags: powershell, outlook

PowerShell 4.0, MS Outlook 2003 SP3

I send the message through Outlook via the function:

```
# Code sources:
# http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_function_send_email.htm
Function Global:Send-Email {
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=0)]
[String]$Address = "abcd@yandex.ru",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=1)]
[String]$Subject = "Hello!",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)]
[String]$Body = "Hello from PowerShell through Outlook."
      )
Begin {
Clear-Host
# Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
    }
Process {
# Create an instance Microsoft Outlook
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "$Address"
$Mail.Subject = $Subject
# $Mail.Body =$Body
$Mail.HTMLBody = "<b>When</b> is swimming?"
$File = "$env:HOMEDRIVE\Temp\1.txt"
$Mail.Attachments.Add($File)
$Mail.Send()
       } # End of Process section
End {
# Section to prevent error message in Outlook
$Outlook.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook)
$Outlook = $null
   } # End of End section!
} # End of function

# Example of using this function
Send-Email #-Address deck@swimmingpool.com
```

When I use it Outlook shows me the window:

[image]

It is the request for operation confirmation. How to get rid of this window?

Comment: What kind of confirmation does the dialog ask for? There might be, say, registry key that controls Outlook's behavior. Some translation for the Russian text is needed to explore such a venue.

Comment: English version (I believe this is the one) : http://www.everythingaccess.com/images/SendEmailWarning.gif

If I remember well, Outlook has to be aware of your anti-virus to let you use Outlook scripts with no warning.

Comment: Yes, @sodawillow is right, this is the same window. But Outlook already knows about antivirus,because I see Kaspersky data inside of the additional tab on the `Option` dialog box of Outlook 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable this warning in Outlook Trustcenter (Options - Trust Center - Programmatic Access), if you need to.

Comment: I don't see `Trust Center` for MS Outlook 2003 SP3. :(

Comment: This option comes in OL 2007 and newer.
For OL 2003 you can try group policy (targetted to your specific client/user).

Comment: Can I do it myself, or it can be done by domain admins only? I never worked with group policies before.

Comment: Group Policies is a domain Feature, but you can try to do this on your personal machine by using gpedit.msc. And you need to get the Office 2003 adm(x) template file.
Its more easy to install a newer version of office though.

Comment: Thank you. It is forbid by admins to install newer Outlook version. I opened `gpedit.msc` with admin rights successfully. Where from can I get the **Office 2003 adm(x) template file**?

Comment: As always at Google ... https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9035

Comment: Thank you, @Martin. I imported it and I am searching necessary option now.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/953806
First Image, the Option "Configure Outlook object model prompt when sending mail" should be the right one.
Please mark the answer, if that does the trick.